# UIButton not disabling using setUserInteractionEnabled:NO and setEnabled:NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, isenabled

Here is the structure of the relevant code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    if(!isResponding) {

    ...

    else {

    ...

    [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [respondButton setEnabled:NO];

    [_manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:usernameEncoded mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];}
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

           ...

           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);

               ...

           }
       }
   ];

   [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [respondButton setEnabled:YES];

   ...

}
```

I've looked, I am not re-enabling the button without knowing it, it never disables. The surrounding code runs. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Try putting breakpoints on your two calls to setEnabled: and in your success and failure blocks.

Comment: ok one sec doing it now

Comment: i ran it and it broke on the first one which was setEnabled:NO - also i dont really know how to use breakpoints

Comment: OK, try using NSLog instead. I bet you will see the problem if you add log messages just before your setEnabled: calls and in your success & failure blocks.

Comment: ok ill do that...but wont they just log whatever? is there something specific i should log?

Comment: both of the log messages just log to console.

Comment: oh haha...i see the problem - it gets set and then unset real quickly...i think i just need to put the re-enabling in a different place

Comment: yep, exactly. You probably want the re-enabling in your success & failure blocks, since they are run after the network request is done.

Comment: thanks for your help giving it a shot now

Comment: yup worked...THANKS! post an answer if you want credit.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code inside the block and it should work.

```
 [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [respondButton setEnabled:NO];

    [_manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:usernameEncoded mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];}
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

           ...

           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);

               ...

           }

           [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
           [respondButton setEnabled:YES];
       }
   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

open user interaction enabled after your network request success or failed

```
[respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[respondButton setEnabled:NO];

[_manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:usernameEncoded mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];}
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

       ...

       failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
           [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
           [respondButton setEnabled:YES];

       }
   }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are close, but I also need the button re-enabled in the `success` block too.

```
[respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[respondButton setEnabled:NO];

[_manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:usernameEncoded mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];}
   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

       [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
       [respondButton setEnabled:YES];
   }
   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

       [respondButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
       [respondButton setEnabled:YES];

   }
}];
```